# Dynamically generate image source using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that somebody helped me with here, it basically converts select options to div elements and displays them with an image alongside them.

```
 $('#property_types option').slice(1).each(
function(){
    var text = $(this).text(),
        outputTo = $('#output'),
        div = $('<div />').text(text),
        img = $('<img />', {'src' : text}).prependTo(div);
    div.appendTo(outputTo);
});
```

right now, the output is as follows:

```
 <div><img src="Apartment" /> Apartment</div>
 <div><img src="Building" /> Building</div>
 <div><img src="Land" /> Land</div>
 <div><img src="Office" /> Office</div>
```

I want to dynamically adjust the src as well.

to make it like:

```
 <div><img src="images/Apartment.png" /> Apartment</div>
 <div><img src="images/Building.png" /> Building</div>
 <div><img src="images/Land.png" /> Land</div>
 <div><img src="images/Office.png" /> Office</div>
```

Comment: use img.attr('href', 'source');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add text to src

```
$('#property_types option').slice(1).each(
function(){
    var text = $(this).text(),
        outputTo = $('#output'),
        div = $('<div />').text(text),
        img = $('<img />', {'src' : 'images/'+text+'.png'}).prependTo(div);
    div.appendTo(outputTo);
});
```

and

```
$('#property_types option').slice(1).each(
function(){
    var text = $(this).text(),
        outputTo = $('#output'),
        div = $('<div />').text(text),
        href = $('<a />', {'href' : '#', 'onclick' : 'go'+text+'();'}).prependTo(div),
        img = $('<img />', {'src' : 'images/'+text+'.png'}).prependTo(href);
    div.appendTo(outputTo);
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

What if I want to add a unique link to each entry? will this break it?

<div><a href="#" onclick="goApartment()"><img src="images/Apartment.png" /> Apartment</a></div>

Comment: you should add it before img, and img prepend to href

Comment: Awesome! This took me hours and I couldn't figure out even the image part! You fixed both the problems, can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $('#property_types option').slice(1).each(function(){
      var text = $(this).text(),
          outputTo = $('#output'),
          div = $('<div />').text(text),
          img = $('<img />', {'src' : 'images/'+text+'.png'}).prependTo(div);
      div.appendTo(outputTo);
 });
```

Comment: Why are you mixing double and single quotes in the src attribute?

Comment: No, they're both allowed. It just makes it harder to read the code if you're inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var source = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e9/Ruby_on_Rails.svg/150px-Ruby_on_Rails.svg.png'
    outputTo = $('#output');
    var div = $('<div />').text('sdfsdfdsf');
    var img = $('<img />').attr('src', source).prependTo(div);
    div.appendTo(outputTo);
});​

​
```